# Change body background color/image when slide changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using Revolution Responsive jQuery Slider ([documentation](http://clapat.ro/themes/creative/doc/rev-documentation.html#!/documenter_cover))and I am trying to achieve an effect where the body background color/image would change when the slide changes.

These what I have got:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrap">
        <div class="fullwidthbanner-container" >
            <div class="fullwidthbanner">
                <ul>  
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE-->
                        <li data-transition="fade, fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1400"  data-saveperformance="off" >
                        <img src="img/web-banner-final-1.png" id="slide1" alt="bg"  data-bgposition="left top" data-bgfit="contain" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>
                        <!-- SLIDE  2-->
                        <li data-transition="fade, fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1400"  data-saveperformance="off" >
                        <img src="img/web-banner-final-2.png" alt="bg" id="slide2" data-bgposition="left top" data-bgfit="contain" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want a green body background (#D5E24D) when slide1 appears, and an background image (abc.jpg) when slide 2 appears.

How should I write the JS?  I am totally new to JS so your help is much appreciated!

Comment: you should add a data attribute to your li for the new background-color / image and then use the [revolution.slide.onchange](http://clapat.ro/themes/creative/doc/rev-documentation.html#!/publicapi) to set the background

Comment: Thank you Pete!  I am also aware that revolution.slide.onchange is the way to go, but I am not sure how to implement it in JS.